# Why the regular expression of the URL rule for the Vutify form validation with port number get error?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

The following URL rule without port number is working well.

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    valid: true,
    url: '',
    urlRules: [
      v => !!v || 'URL is required',
      v => (v && v.length <= 256) || 'URL must be less than 256 characters',
      v => /https?:\/\/[\w!?/\+\-_~=;\.,*&@#$%\(\)\'\[\]]+/.test(v) || 'URL must be valid',
    ],
  }),
  components: {
  },
}
```

Then, I've put `[0-9]*` rule for port number part of the URL as follows.

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    valid: true,
    url: '',
    urlRules: [
      v => !!v || 'URL is required',
      v => (v && v.length <= 256) || 'URL must be less than 256 characters',
      v => /https?:[0-9]*\/\/[\w!?/\+\-_~=;\.,*&@#$%\(\)\'\[\]]+/.test(v) || 'URL must be valid',
    ],
  }),
  components: {
  },
}
```

But this occurs following error:

```
  34:36  error  Unnecessary escape character: \+  no-useless-escape
  34:44  error  Unnecessary escape character: \.  no-useless-escape
  34:53  error  Unnecessary escape character: \(  no-useless-escape
  34:55  error  Unnecessary escape character: \)  no-useless-escape
  34:57  error  Unnecessary escape character: \'  no-useless-escape
  34:59  error  Unnecessary escape character: \[  no-useless-escape

✖ 6 problems (6 errors, 0 warnings)
```

I have no idea why the additional port number part breaks the regular expression. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not related to vuetify rules or regular expressions. You should take a look to your ESLint config. This error said that your code failed "no-useless-escape" ESLint rule.

As a quick workaround, you could disable ESLint rule for some lines.
This code should work:

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    valid: true,
    url: '',
    urlRules: [
      v => !!v || 'URL is required',
      v => (v && v.length <= 256) || 'URL must be less than 256 characters', /* eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-escape*/
      v => /https?:[0-9]*\/\/[\w!?/\+\-_~=;\.,*&@#$%\(\)\'\[\]]+/.test(v) || 'URL must be valid',
    ],
  }),
  components: {
  },
}
```

Comment: Aha! This was from the eslint! 
Thank you dreamwalker!